# Editing "parameters.yml" manually and running "composer.phar update"

Tags: symfony

Im adding manually a line to the end of parameters.yml like this:

```
base_url_algoritmo: /var/www/myproject/SpectralMatchingLinux/
```

The problem when run php composer.phar update I get this lines:

> ```
> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
> ```
>
> You have requested a non-existent parameter "base_url_algoritmo".

so just after that I open `parameters.yml` and I find that the line I have just added is not anymore there!, any help?

Im using symfony 2.3

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that any parameters you add to your `app/config/parameters.yml` are replicated with defaults in your `app/config/parameters.yml.dist`.

This is due to the `incenteev/composer-parameter-handler`and post install/update command `Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters`.

When run this script/command will make sure that any parameters named in your `parameters.yml.dist` are set in your `parameters.yml` and clear out any others (not in `.dist`).

Answer (score 0):

In config.yml add this:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: settings.yml }
   [- more imports ...]
```

Then create a new yaml file settings.yml and add this:

```
parameters:
    base_url_algoritmo: /var/www/myproject/SpectralMatchingLinux/
```